# Can't get form to work when trying to create new item in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am just starting to learn Ruby on Rails on my own, and my main source of learning is from online sites such as here and codecademy, which only does an OK job at actually explaining what's happening when I code.

My project is a very simple IT Inventory site, that displays a database with info on items. This is to practice with CRUD, and right now I am stuck on the create part. Whenever I click a link on my main page, it is suppose to go to a page with a form on it that they can enter and then submit, but it won't even display the page with the form. Here is my current code.

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get '/items' => 'items#index' 
get 'items/new' => 'items#new'
post 'items' => 'items#create'
root 'items#index'  #homepage and /items are same page for now
```

**Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @items = InventoryItem.all
end

def new
    @item = InventoryItem.new
end

def create
    @item = InventoryItem.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
        redirect_to '/items'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private
def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit( :idnumber, :vutag, :fund, :dept, :bldg, :person, :mfct, :mfctdate, :commonname, :modelnum, :serial, :cost)
end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>  
<div> 
  <%= f.label :inventoryitem %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :idnumber %><br> 
  <%= f.text_area :vutag %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :fund %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :dept %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :bldg %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :person %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :mfct %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :mfctdate %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :commonname %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :modelnum %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :serial %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :cost %><br>
</div> 
<div> 
  <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
</div> 
<% end %>
```

**index.html**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>IDNum</th>
  <th>VU Tag</th>
  <th>Fund</th>
  <th>Dept</th>
  <th>Bldg</th>
  <th>Person</th>
  <th>Mfct</th>
  <th>Mfct Date</th>
  <th>Common Name</th>
  <th>Model</th>
  <th>Serial</th>
  <th>Cost</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
  <td> <%= item.idnumber %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.vutag %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.fund %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.dept %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.bldg %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.person %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.mfct %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.mfctdate %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.commonname %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.modelnum %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.serial %> </td>
  <td> <%= item.cost %> </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<%= link_to "New Entry", "items/new" %>
```

A very basic app to display info from a database. (I'll go back and make it pretty once it works.

The page that displays the table works fine, its when I click on the link and go to items/new that it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError in Items#new 
Showing /home/group3/ITSite/app/views/items/new.html.erb where line #1 raised: 
undefined method `inventory_items_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8b11137718>:0x007f8b10012fc8>


Extracted source (around line #1): 
    <%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>  
    <div> 
    <%= f.label :inventoryitem %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :idnumber %><br> 
    <%= f.text_area :vutag %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :fund %><br>

Rails.root: /home/group3/ITSite

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace 
app/views/items/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_items_new_html_erb__1490812464141641456_70117522166260'
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the error is and where I need to fix it? I don't believe its the html page itself, but rather something leading up to that, or something named wrong. The naming convention in Ruby on Rails throws me off a little bit.

Comment: Could you add the output of `rake routes` to the question?

Comment: Follow the naming conventions as mentioned by Tom . More Possibility that it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails uses convention over configuration. What that means is that names are important. Your model is InventoryItem. Therefore your controller should be called InventoryItemsController.

In your routes, as Vasfed mentioned, the convention is to use the resources method to generate the necessary paths. So rather than `get '/items/new'`, etc just use `resources :inventory_items`.

Let's say you make those changes. In your InventoryItemsController `new` action, set `@inventory_item = InventoryItem.new`. Of course, you can call your variables whatever you want but it makes sense to call it what it actually is. That's why I'm suggesting `@inventory_item`. Good so far?

In your form, do this: `form_for(@inventory_item) do |f|`. Rails will automatically translate that into a "new" path for that model instance: `new_inventory_item_path` (aka inventory_items/new).

Answer (score 0):

Use `resources` in routes, it creates named routes along with routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items, only:[:index, :new, :create]
  root 'items#index'
end
```

Also you should name model the same as controller and route, for defaults to work